# Using Replace Strings to Match a User

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, str-replace

I'm creating a small application that is supposed to create a leaderboard. I'm trying to match the users last name from the system.

The replace string is

```
var lastName = '{LastName}'
```

I would then like the application to match the replace string to the object in the users array that I created so that it shows their points at the top.

Here is the JSON:

```
$scope.users = [
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'One', 'created': 15, 'replied': 13, 'read': 1151},
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'Two', 'created': 13, 'replied': 24, 'read': 180},
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'Three', 'created': 2, 'replied': 18, 'read': 157},
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'Four', 'created': 12, 'replied': 7, 'read': 91},
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'Five', 'created': 13, 'replied': 4, 'read': 153},
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'Six', 'created': 12, 'replied': 2, 'read': 32},
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'Seven', 'created': 10, 'replied': 1, 'read': 5},
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'Eight', 'created': 9, 'replied': 0, 'read': 59},
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'Nine', 'created': 0, 'replied': 1, 'read': 54},
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'Ten', 'created': 0, 'replied': 0, 'read': 3},
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'Eleven', 'created': 6, 'replied': 0, 'read': 10},
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'Twelve', 'created': 15, 'replied': 0, 'read': 6},
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'Thirteen', 'created': 0, 'replied': 0, 'read': 15},
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'Fourteen', 'created': 2, 'replied': 7, 'read': 9},
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'Fifteen', 'created': 10, 'replied': 1, 'read': 97},
    {'firstName': 'Person', 'lastName': 'Sixteen', 'created': 18, 'replied': 14, 'read': 1087}
]
```

The application shows the top ten users in a list and is filtered from highest-to-lowest value for each point (created, replied and read).

How can I match the replace string of **lastName** with the object key **lastName** so that I can also show the user what their rank or point score is if they are not in the top ten?

Plunker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nay1SeNjWcg30OLz73xI?p=preview

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filterFilter` module, to filter your dict by a given attribute.

```
filterFilter($scope.users,{lastName: example_last_name});
```